# Prove $\triangle{ABC}$ is isosceles if $\cos A = \frac{\sin B}{2\sin C}$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

In $\triangle{ABC}$, $$\cos A = \frac{\sin B}{2\sin C}$$
How to prove that $\triangle{ABC}$ is isosceles?

Comment: Writing the relation as $2 \cos A = \sin B/\sin C$, the Law of Cosines allows you to rewrite the left-hand side of the equation in terms of side lengths, and the Law of Sines allows you to rewrite the right-hand side in terms of side lengths.

Comment: i did this... may be there was a calculation mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the law of cosines $$\cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}$$ and the law of sines $$\sin B=\frac{b}{2R},\ \ \ \sin C=\frac{c}{2R}$$ where $R$ is the radius of the circumscribed circle of $\triangle{ABC}$, we have
$$\frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=\frac{\frac{b}{2R}}{2\cdot\frac{c}{2R}}\iff \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=\frac{b}{2c}$$$$\iff b^2+c^2-a^2=b^2\iff (c+a)(c-a)=0\iff c=a.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using [Werner Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)s, $$2\cos A\sin C=\sin(C+A)+\sin(C-A)$$

Now $\sin(C+A)=\sin(\pi-B)=\sin B$

Consequently, $\sin(C-A)=0\implies C-A=n\pi$

Now  $0<A,C<\pi\implies|C-A|<\pi\implies C-A=0$

and consequently, $c=2R\sin C=2R\sin A=a$

Answer (score 1):

You may refer to the following figure:

[image]

The three red lines are the altitudes of the triangle.

$$\cos A=\frac{\sin B}{2\sin C}
\\ \implies \frac{AD}{AB}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{AE/AB}{AE/AC} =\frac{1}{2}\frac{AC}{AB}
\\ \implies AD=\frac{AC}{2}$$

Then $BD$ cuts $AC$ in half. As $\triangle ADB \cong\triangle CDB$ $(SAS)$ and $BA=BC$, $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles.